# Filter out rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

I have many derived tables in Power BI and I have a table having a list of ids.

Derived tables are like this -

Table 1 -

| IDs | Value | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Two | US - 50878 |
| A2 | Three | US - 50879 |
| A3 | Four | US - 50888 |
| A4 | Five | US - 50898 |

Table 2 -

| IDs | Value | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A3 | Two | US - 50878 |
| A4 | Three | US - 50879 |
| A5 | Four | US - 50888 |
| A6 | Five | US - 50898 |

Like that, I have many tables in Power BI.

I have an exception table having a list of ids and my requirement is to filter out the above-derived table based on the ids available in the exception table.

Like my exception table is -

| ids |
| --- |
| A3 |
| A4 |

Since A3 and A4 are in the exception table then Table 1 and Table 2 should not contain these 2 ids rows.

Expected results should be

Table 1 -

| IDs | Value | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Two | US - 50878 |
| A2 | Three | US - 50879 |

Table 2 -

| IDs | Value | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | Four | US - 50888 |
| A6 | Five | US - 50898 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Transform Data, do a left anti join merge between each table and your exceptions.

[image]

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Hi Davide can you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632489/create-summary-table-from-many-tables-power-bi

Comment: Hi Davide. By any chance is it possible to exclude the Exception column from the final table?

Comment: Just delete the final column.