# Create summary table from many tables Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have many tables and from that, I need to create a summary table.

Table 1 -

| IDs | PSC id | PSC | ACV id | ACV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A3 | True | 2 | False | 4 |
| A4 | True | 3 | True | 1 |
| A5 | False | 4 | False | 4 |
| A6 | False | 5 | True | 6 |

Table 2 -

| IDs | PSC id | PSC | ACV id | ACV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | True | 12 | False | 7 |
| A6 | True | 3 | True | 3 |
| A7 | False | 4 | False | 4 |
| A9 | False | 5 | True | 1 |

The summary table should be like this (summation of all True and Summation of all False )

| Table | ACV | PSC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table 1- True | 7 | 5 |
| Table 1 -False | 8 | 9 |
| Table 2- True | 4 | 15 |
| Table 2 -False | 11 | 9 |

Comment: Are  you happy with a Power Query solution?

Comment: Yes, It is. Actually, I am doing the summation of ACV and PSC  based on their flags.
If ACV is True find the summation and False then find the Summation. Both flags have different flag columns.

Comment: I have around 5 tables like above and I need to find the summary of that.

Comment: @DavideBacci can u please check this I have updated my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874664/add-new-column-based-upon-filter-power-bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't straightforward - maybe Ron or Horseyride have better ideas.

Add a custom column to each table with the table name. e.g.
[image]

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Append queries as new:

[image]

Appended table:

[image]

Group exactly as follows:

[image]

[image]

Add a custom column:

[image]

```
List.Sum( Table.SelectRows(Source, (x)=> x[Custom] = [Custom] and x[ACV id] = [PSC id])[ACV])
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Hi David. The above tables are derived tables. So we are not getting options for custom columns for them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hi Davide can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76635556/summarize-multiple-tables-into-one-table

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version that does NOT require adjusting the initial tables at all

```
// assumes all table to combine start with Table and are the only queries to do so
let Source =  Table.SelectRows(Record.ToTable(#sections[Section1]), each Text.StartsWith([Name], "Table")),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(Source[Value], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Value", List,List),
Combined =  Table.AddColumn(Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Name", "PSC id", "PSC"}),{{"PSC id", "id"}, {"PSC", "value"}}), "Type", each "PSC")
         &  Table.AddColumn(Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Name", "ACV id", "ACV"}),{{"ACV id", "id"}, {"ACV", "value"}}), "Type", each "ACV"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Combined, {{"id", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Name", "id"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Merged Columns", List.Distinct(#"Merged Columns"[Type]), "Type", "value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```