# Summarize multiple tables into one table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

I have many tables ( derived from a single table ) like.

Table 1 -

| ID | PSC | BWC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 | 1 |
| B1 | 3 | 8 |
| C1 | 4 | 7 |
| D1 | 5 | 6 |
| **Total** | **14** | **22** |

Table 2 -

| ID | PSC | BWC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| q1 | 5 | 11 |
| d1 | 3 | 8 |
| f1 | 4 | 7 |
| qw1 | 5 | 6 |
| **Total** | **17** | **32** |

Table 3-

| ID | PSC | BWC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aq1 | 5 | 11 |
| as1 | 3 | 8 |
| sf1 | 14 | 7 |
| qsw1 | 5 | 16 |
| **Total** | **27** | **42** |

My expectation is -

Summary table -

| Name | PSC | BWC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Expiry | 14 | 22 |
| Renew | 17 | 32 |
| DOD | 27 | 42 |

Comment: Can you explain the logic to get your summary table? Do you want DAX or Power Query?

Comment: Hi Davide.

The total of Table 1 goes to the first row as Expiry ( 14 , 22 ) . Similar to that other totals of the remaining two tables go to other rows and I have given their name as renew and DOD.
Any solution is fine DAX would be better.

Comment: Do the totals already exist on Table 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, from format visuals we can enable it from the total option. We have that value available in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Summary Table = 
UNION(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Table1,"Name", "Expiry", "PSC", SUM(Table1[PSC]), "BWC", SUM(Table1[BWC])      
    ),
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Table2,"Name", "Renew", "PSC", SUM(Table2[PSC]), "BWC", SUM(Table2[BWC])      
    ),
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Table3,"Name", "DOD", "PSC", SUM(Table3[PSC]), "BWC", SUM(Table3[BWC])      
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the formula:

```
    Summary table = SELECTCOLUMNS(
 UNION(
     ADDCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE('Table 1','Table 1'[ID]="Total"),"Name","Expiry"),
     ADDCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE('Table 2','Table 2'[ID]="Total"),"Name","Renew"),
     ADDCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE('Table 3','Table 3'[ID]="Total"),"Name","DOD")),
"Name",[Name],"PSC",[PSC],"BWC",[BWC])
```

[image]