# Add new column based upon filter power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables -

Table A -

| Seller | income |
| --- | --- |
| Ron | 12 |
| Saw | 11 |
| harry | 13 |
| Jon | 14 |

Filter_table having seller name only-

| Seller |
| --- |
| Ron |
| Saw |

I need to add a column in Table A based on Filter_table. If the seller's name is available filter_table then copy the same value from income to the new column if seller's name is not available then put a zero on that row.

Expected output would be -

Table A -

| Seller | income | New_colum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 12 | 12 |
| Saw | 11 | 11 |
| harry | 13 | 0 |
| Jon | 14 | 0 |

Since Ron and saw was available the copy the same value in new_column and in other we put zero.

I am trying below things but it not applying the filter.

> Blockquote

New_column = IFERROR (
VALUE ( '418k'[Total_items] ),
0,
FILTER('418k','418k'[Seller] IN VALUES (Active_seller_power_BI[Seller])
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

New Column = IF(TableA[Seller] IN VALUES(filter_table[Seller]), TableA[income], 0)

Answer (score 1):

Write a measure in DAX

```
Measure = LOOKUPVALUE('Table A'[income],'Table A'[Seller], MAX(Filter_table[Seller]),0)
```

[image]

Comment: In some places, there might be an error as well so we need to add zero in that case. can u please cover that?

Comment: Also, I need a column can u please add a column because I am using it in another query and probably dax wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add column in the data view,

```
New Column = if(ISBLANK(RELATED(Filter_table[Seller])),0,'Table A'[Income])
```

[image: Data view]

both tables must be connected in the model view
[image: Model view]